# Get the variation for specific attributes key value pairs in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I would like get variation of an product to specific KEY / VALUE attributes like this :

**Variation 1** : Key attribute "Color" Value attribute "Blue" | Key attribute "Size" Value attribute "XS"  
**Variation 2** : Key attribute "Color" Value attribute "Yellow" | Key attribute "Size" Value attribute "X"

I would like get the **Variation 2**, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following commented code:

```
global $product; // The main product variation

// OR
// $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
// OR
// $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );

$color_found = $size_found = false;
$variation_id = 0;

// Loop through all available variations for the variable product
foreach($product->get_available_variations() as $child ){
    foreach($child['attributes'] as $key => $value ){
        $taxonomy  = str_replace('attribute_', '', $key);
        $attr_name = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy )->labels->singular_name; // Attribute name
        $term_name = get_term_by( 'slug', $value, $taxonomy )->name; // Value name

        if( $attr_name == 'Color' && $term_name == 'Yellow' )
            $color_found = true;

        if( $attr_name == 'Size' && $term_name == 'X' )
            $size_found = true;

        if($color_found && $size_found )
            break; // we stop the loop
    }
    if($color_found && $size_found ){
        $variation_id = $child['variation_id']; // Get and set the varition ID
        break; // we stop the loop
    }
}
// Get an instance of the WC_Product_Variarion object
$variation = wc_get_product($variation_id);

// Displaying the variation ID  
echo 'Variation ID: '.$variation_id.'<br>';
```

You will get the corresponding  [`WC_Product_Variarion` object](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_Variation.html) instance and be able to use on it all `WC_Product` and `WC_Product_Variarion` methods.

> It can also be done in a similar way using [`$product->get_children()` method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_Variable.html#_get_children)

Comment: Consider the WooCommerce bultin function WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT::find_matching_product_variation()

Comment: @user9372991 Thanks, you are right… *("built in" may be)*… You should *consider* to get/set a custom name over your anonymous *user9372991*, as you are certainly not a Product Sku   :) ...